# Как определить продолжительность видео файла JavaScript и вывести его на сайте?

Tags: javascript, youtube

Подскажите как с помощью JavaScript вывести на сайте общее время видео файла.

пробовал написать такой скрипт но он  не работает.

```js
(function (window) {
    var videoNode = window.document.querySelector("#myvideo");
    var timeNode = window.document.querySelector("#time");
    videoNode.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function (e) {
        var duration = videoNode.duration.toFixed(1);
        var m = duration % 60;
        timeNode.innerText =
            Math.floor(duration / 60) + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") + m;
    });
})
(window);
```

```html
        <div id="div-timefile"><a id="time"></a></div>
        <video id="myvideo" class="video_list_item" muted="" <?=$autoplay?> >
               <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOVQAfLiYdY>" controls="" autoplay="" muted="">
        </video>
```

**вот как это выглядит в моём коде **

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отобразить общее время видеофайла на веб-сайте с помощью JavaScript, вы можете использовать свойство продолжительности (`duration`) объекта `HTMLVideoElement`. Это свойство возвращает продолжительность видео в секундах.

Вот пример того, как вы можете использовать это свойство для отображения общей продолжительности видео на веб-странице:

```html
<html>
<body>

<video id="myVideo" src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-5s.mp4" controls></video>

<p>Total time: <span id="totalTime"></span></p>

<script>
  var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  var totalTime = document.getElementById("totalTime");
  
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
    // Display the total time of the video in the span element
    totalTime.innerHTML = video.duration + " seconds";
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

В этом примере мы сначала получаем ссылку на элемент `video` и элемент `span` `totalTime`, используя их атрибуты `id`. Затем мы добавляем прослушиватель событий для события `loadmetadata`, которое запускается, когда браузер загружает метаданные для видео (включая продолжительность). Внутри прослушивателя событий мы обновляем `innerHTML` элемента `span` `totalTime`, чтобы отобразить общее время видео.

Обратите внимание, что этот метод будет работать только в том случае, если видеофайл уже загружен браузером. Если видео передается с сервера, браузеру может потребоваться некоторое время, чтобы получить метаданные и инициировать событие `loadmetadata`. В этом случае вам может потребоваться использовать другой метод для отображения общего времени видео, например, получить его с сервера или использовать событие `timeupdate` для обновления отображения во время воспроизведения видео.

Comment: я скопировал ваш код и вставил но почему-то у меня на странице не отображается длительность. Сайт http://novostipw.beget.tech/ .